# from VB to Java Factorial Method

Tags: java, vba

In VBA code, here is the loop:

```
For i = 0 To 50
    sum = sum + Exp(-lambda * T) * (lambda * T) ^ i / Application.Fact(i) * X
 Next
```

In Java I converted to code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
   sum = sum + Math.exp(-lambda * T) * Math.pow(lambda * T , i) / (i*=1) * X;           
}
```

But It didnt work. Any idea how to write Application.Fact(i) function in Java?

Comment: Instead of calling a method, you're repeatedly multiplying `i` by 1.  And regardless of what's in `i`, that value will always be zero (you start with an initial zero).

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement `factorial(i)` yourself in Java.

Just a hint: make sure it does not overflow.
If needed use the `BigInteger` class (from the Java libraries).

Comment: To add onto this, a factorial method with a memory would improve efficiency from roughly `O(n^2)` down to `O(n)`.

Comment: I didn't specify recursive or iterative, memoization or not. OP can optimize it as needed. I haven't seen a factorial with time complexity O(n^2) btw.